# How do I replace 2x4 outdoor decking with 1x4 hardwood decking?

Tags: floor, deck, joists

I have a small entry area deck outside my front door, roughly 70 sqft.  The deck is currently made of 2x4's and a few 2x6's screwed into ~16" on center floor joists.

I replaced the front door and siding.  I now want to replace the deck surface.  I am thinking of replacing the current 2x4 and 2x6 boards with 1x4 hardwood deck boards.

I can unscrew the current 2x4 floor boards, but then how do I makeup for the 3/4" difference (2x vs 1x) in floor board thickness?

I want the new deck to work with the current door threshold height.  Will I need to replace the current floor joists?

Comment: Why not just attach some 1x boards to the joists to shim them 3/4" higher?

Comment: Oh, whoops I see.  Is there some standard way that people do this?  Maybe this is it.  Are you suggesting that I take 1x something boards, rip these into 1x2 (3/4” x 1 ½”) boards, screw the 1 ½” face of these boards to the joists, and then nail the decking into these?  I could do this.  Does this stand the test of time?  What kind of wood might I use for this?  The current joists are made of pressure treated lumber.